# Webdriver doesn't move the slider to the correct value

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here, I am passing 30. But after running the code slider moves to 20 only. Doesn't move to the correct value that I am passing in the code.

```
By slider_humidity = By.xpath("//mat-slider[@formcontrolname = 'humidity']");
WebElement hSlider = driver.findElement(slider_humidity);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.clickAndHold(hSlider);
action.moveByOffset(30,0);
action.build().perform();
```

[image]

Comment: Which website are you using

Comment: It is a client project of my company

Comment: what is the initial value of slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two things you should keep in mind are:**

```
action.clickAndHold(hSlider);
```

Clicks the center of the element , so current slider will be always 50% in this case

**Second**

The below line of code is not moving the slider by value but by pixel, **so 30px != 30 value on slider**

```
action.moveByOffset(30,0);
```

**So what you have to do is:**

```
action.moveToElement​(hSlider,0,0) //this will make it to start at 0,0 of the slider
action.clickAndHold() //don't pass the element, now it will click current mouse location which is (0,0)
action.moveByOffset(30,0); // move by 30 pixel from 0
action.build().perform();
```

**you can find the full size of the slider using inspect**

eg in below slider max offset you can move is (129,0) and min is (0,0)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this way. But still getting the same thing. Passed 30 but moves only upto 20.

Comment: Pass 40,0 , means 30% of 129